# Having issues getting content from text files to output correctly

Tags: c++

The program involves outputting a joke and punchline to the user from associated text files. The joke file should display the entire contents of the file, while the punchline file should only display the last line of text (the prior lines are random characters that are not meant`enter code here` to be read).

The problem I am experiencing is that the joke file content outputs on numerous lines, when it should all be on the same line. Here is the content of the joke file.

I started a band called 999 megabytes...

It is outputting as follows...

```
I
started
a
band
called
999
megabytes...
```

The punchline file is reading from the last row, but only displaying the last word in the row. Here is the contents of the file...

```
asfasdfasdfasdfsdf
asdfasdfsadfsadfsadf
asdfsadfsdfsdf
We haven't gotten a gig yet.

Here is what is outputting to the screen...

yet.

I have checked the file for any odd carriage return line feeds, but none are present that would explain this. Any assistance is tremendously appreciated, as I have been plugging away at this for hours to no avail.

Here is my code...

/*Include Section*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

/*Namespace Section*/
using namespace std;

/*Function Prototypes Section*/
void displayAllLines(ifstream &inFile);
void displayLastLine(ifstream &infile);

/*Main section: this is the entry point of the program, which controls the flow of execution*/
int main()
{
    string file1;
    string file2;
    ifstream joke;
    ifstream punchline;
    char decision;
    char y;
    char n;
/*Beginning of program. Prompts user, asking them if they are ready to proceed. If yes, will display the joke\punchline. If no, 
ends program sequence*/

    cout << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << setw(48) << "Punchline Program" << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the Punchline Program!" << endl;
    cout << "Are you ready to hear a joke? (y or n):  ";
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == 'y')
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Great! Prepare to laugh!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (decision == 'n')

    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ah, no sense of humor, I see. Time to make like a tree and leaf (queue rimshot)!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
/*When user chooses "y", the following opens joke and punchline text files, outputting them to the user. The punchline file will
only display the last line of the file to the user*/
    joke.open("joke.txt");
    punchline.open("punchline.txt");
    cout << endl;
    displayAllLines(joke);
    displayLastLine(punchline);
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void displayAllLines(ifstream &infile)
{
    string text;
    while (infile >> text)
    {
        cout << text << endl;
    }
}


void displayLastLine(ifstream &infile)
{
    string text;
    while (infile >> text);
    {
        cout << text << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `std::getline`.  The stream input operator for strings will only read a "word".

Comment: thank you for the update, paddy. Could you please show me where in the code I should change this and how? I'd imagine its within the function for void displayLastLine, but I'm not sure what adjustment to make

Comment: Imagine that you've just been told exactly what function to use to read lines of text.  What you do is go and look up a reference or example for how to use that function.  And if you have any problems, you come back and ask a question.  Or do a [StackOverflow search for that function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline) and see what turns up.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (infile >> text);
```

`operator>>` does not read an entire line of text. It reads a single whitespace-delimited word. This is why you end up showing only the last word in the file. You're reading the file wrong.

The correct function that reads an entire line of text is `std::getline()`:

```
string text;
string lastline;

while (getline(infile, text))
     lastline=text;

cout << lastline << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam! I made the changes to the program and the punchline displays as needed. I tried doing the same thing to the joke to see if it will display all on one line, but nothing displays now. I had it all outputting with my original code, but it was on multiple lines instead of just all one line. I checked the file for any odd carriage return line feeds, but nothing was showing out of sorts. I've done several searches on how to correct this, but nothing is coming up that will work.